# Recursive audio solution

Tags: c, recursion, audio

I just want to get my head wrapped around recursion using something simple. I want amplitudes from 1 to -1. This will take less than two minutes.

I just through together a recursive solution to practice recursing.

```
/* This program outputs amplitudes within a frequency of 440Hz. 
   The number of audio samples will add of up to 1024, and the highest frequency 
   We can generate is about 20KilHz. 
*/
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<math.h> 
#define PI 3.141597 
#define TwoPI (2*3.141597) 
#define SampleRate 441000
#define Frequency 440 
#define Buffer 1024
/* Recursively Generates Signal, it is called in main. */ 
/*int CalculateSignal(int Sampler){
    Sampler=0; 
    int Sample= 0; 
    Sample=sin(Frequency*TwoPI*SampleRate);

    printf("%.6f",Sample);

    if(Sampler==Buffer){

        return Sample; 
    }

    else if(Sampler<Buffer){
        return CalculateSignal(Sampler+1);
    }
}*/
int main(){

    CalculateSignal(1024);

}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Can you add some comments to the code to say what it's doing? I'd say for *audio*, at least in this scenario, you should use ALSA or PulseAudio.

Comment: I got an infinite loop. I don't care about hearing anything just understanding recursion.

Comment: A few observations: 

1: This is definitely not a great place to be using recursion - you're going to get a 1024 recursive stack-frames - this may overflow your stack, and if not, will be difficult and slow to debug.
2: Do you intend to store the sample in the buffer?  Your code doesn't - and if that's you intention, you don't need to return the sample out of each iteration.